# Getting rid of the little (+) buttons for a clean window

Tags: 3d-view, video-sequence-editor, video

I wanted to have a second window (with a 3D View) totally clean for projection.

Anyone have any idea how to get rid of the little **(+) buttons** on the side, the ones that show up when you press T or N key to hide the side toolbars?

Editing the code and compiling Blender again, I guess.
Could some one help me or point me the way.

Comment: You mean the Toggle Window Fullscreen in the menu.

Comment: You still can not get rid of the (+) at the side

Comment: Your totally right .

Comment: I was trying in blender 2.8 and did't do anything.

Comment: In 2.8 is Ctrl-Alt-Spacebar. Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

*2.79*

1. Duplicate the [area into a new window](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/areas.html#duplicate-area-into-new-window).
   **`View ‣ Duplicate Area into new Window`**
   **OR**
   [Duplicate a window](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/areas.html#toggle-fullscreen-area) with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>
   Info area ‣ **`Window ‣ Duplicate Window`**
2. Then, [Toggle Area Fullscreen](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/areas.html#toggle-maximize-area) <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd>. **`View ‣ Toggle Fullscreen Area`**
3. Eliminiate additional 3D View icons in the User Preferences <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> under *Interface* ‣ *Display* (on the left)

---

2.8

Although the manual [says the same](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/window_system/areas.html#toggle-fullscreen-area) as in 2.79. The *Toggle Fullscreen Area* is somewhere else in 2.8 (2018-10-12).

3D View Menu: **`View ‣ Area ‣ Toggle Fullscreen Area`**. <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>

Comment: The hotkey tooltip says something about *ActionZone*, which I don't understand though.

Comment: in 2.8 still not totally clean, on the bottom left, the Last Operator thing is still there.

Comment: @Joao Selection doesn't toggle the Last Operator thing. A simple ***A*** keyboard press will remove it.